# UV mapping a texture generated from a script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, procedural-generation, uv-mapping

I would like to create a simple material in Unity 3D using a C# script.

My idea: I would create an array of points with coordinates then use these points to define shapes with a class (lets say squares) which would also contain their colors and feed these shapes with their information into a shader which would then display them (using the points' coordinates as UV coordinates).

Example (image below): Lets say I have a mesh of two triangles making a square. And 9 points in the script lets say (0,0) (0,0.5) (0,1) (0.5,0) (0.5,0.5) (0.5,1) (1,0) (1,0.5) (1,1) and that would make 4 squares with different colors on the mesh.

[image: Example]

How do I approach this correctly to define the squares in the script and project them onto the mesh?

Also this is a simplified version of what I want to do. Eventually I'd like to do this on a sphere and use the information from the class to for example display different actual textures in each shape.

I tried to google this problem but I didn't find many results. Maybe I just don't know the right terms because it doesn't seem to me as a very difficult thing to achieve. I just don't know where to begin.

Comment: This is very opinion based but generally what renderers will do is have a `Mesh` object which has a property of type `Triangle[]` where `Triangle` is basically just 3 vectors: `[ (0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 0) ]` All your UV data can be interpolated between the points of each triangle

Comment: in order to have multiple textures on the same object you will have to use multiple textures overlayed .. and then you would set the various according [`uv`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-uv.html) up to [`uv8`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-uv8.html) - maybe not understanding what exactly you are asking

Comment: I see your points guys but I think you misunderstood me. I want to have objects with some properties (color, vertices etc.) defined in the script (or a JSON - doesn't really matter), these objects would then somehow be mapped onto the mesh using their properties. My question is how do I make the shader use these properties to display them onto the mesh correctly. If that is even possible. Essentially similar to having an svg instead of a bitmap as a texture.

Comment: @derHugo is wrong, an object can have multiple material slots. however, it is less performant than having a single material slot, as each material slot adds to the number of draw calls of the renderer. As to how to generate a texture with code, are you sure generating textures is the way to go? perhaps you can instead try and modify vertex colors in real-time (just an idea though)

Comment: I suggest looking up ways to change vertex colors through script. this seems promising https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-colors.html
. if you tried to generate textures in real time using some 2D image generation library, it would be a huge pain to set vertex coordinates, and you would have to deal with UV mapping. I really don't think that's the right direction for you to choose.

Comment: @Mephisto how am wrong? ^^ That's literally what I said and if you want to use multiple textures then yes you would go that way ... of course you can also combine multiple textures together and UV map this way sure